# SQL Select all rows per group if a condition is met at least once

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table `variable` that looks like this:

| id | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 3 |
| 2 | C | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 3 | A | 2 |
| 3 | B | 2 |
| 4 | C | 3 |
| 5 | A | 2 |

I would like to select only the ids where at least one `V2 = 3`, to get something like this:

| id | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 3 |
| 2 | C | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 4 | C | 3 |

What is the SQL query to do this?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually ise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select *
From yourtable 
where id in ( 
             select distinct id
             from yourtable
             where v2 = 3
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select v.* from variable01 v where id in (select distinct id from variable01 where V2=3 ) ;
```

Working demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd7175/1

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem, I usually recommend `exists` because it optimizes better across more databases (with the right indexing):

```
select v.*
from variable v
where exists (select 1
              from variable v2
              where v2.id = v.id and
                    v2.v2 = 3
             );
```

You can also express this quite well using `in`.  But importantly, `select distinct` is not needed in the subquery:

```
select v.*
from variable v
where v.id in (select v2.id
               from variable v2
               where v2.v2 = 3
              );
```